# Getting width of text in UITextView (custom font)

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have UITextView with custom font (ttf file), it works perfect, but when I am trying to get text's width with following code

```
UITextView*textInput;



CGFloat width1 =  [textInput.text sizeWithFont:textInput.font].width;


frame.size.width=width1;
textInput.frame = frame;
```

it doesn't work correct: width1 is less then real width of text..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now in your code I don't know what's textInput, but probably is a string without the real font  that the UITextView uses.
UITextView has the property attributedText, through which you can obtain a NSAttributedString.
After this you can obtain the size:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString=[myTextView attributedText];
NSSize size=[attributedString size];
```

Then size.width will be the width.

Comment: I render layer of this TextView using size of it's frame, draw image at TextViews coords  and remove original TextView

Comment: After you have calculated the size, try to convert it.You are moving from the text view to another view, so use convertSize:fromView.

Comment: Works well. Sounds stupid but make sure you actually set the text first. i forgot

Comment: I am on iOS 10 now with Swift 3, the UITextView.attributedText.size() does not take text wrap into consideration, although the text are already wrapped, the height always = single line height, width always = width when text is not wrapped, any ideas? @RamyAlZuhouri